# How to pick up a value instead of the sum in a list?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a web application that need to draw charts. For that, my controller sends some list in `ViewBag` and `chart.js` do the rest . But, for one `View`, I need to select all the consumption of a vehicle one by one. I don't know how to select each record , but I can select the sum of all of them.

My code for the sum is:

```
public ActionResult choice(string Snom , DateTime? date1 , DateTime? date2 ) // Snom is an input in an inputbox , to select a vehicle
{
    var veh = from s in db.Fuel
              select s;
    var list = veh.ToList();

    List<double?> repartitions = new List<double?>();

    var comp = list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Distinct(); // I select only the records for the selected vehicle
    foreach (var item in comp)
    {
        repartitions.Add(list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Sum(x => x.Volume)); // This is the line that i need to change 

    }
    var rep = repartitions;
    ViewBag.COMP = comp; // I place it in Viewbag 
    ViewBag.REP = repartitions.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

How can I do that?

I know that I already posted a question like this but situation has changed and needed some changes.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

With the answer, I tried this code:

```
public ActionResult choice(string Snom , DateTime? date1 , DateTime? date2 ) // Snom is an input in an inputbox , to select a vehicle
{
    var veh = from s in db.Fuel
              select s;
    var list = veh.ToList();

    List<double?> repartitions = new List<double?>();

    var comp = list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Distinct(); // I select only the records for the selected vehicle
    foreach (var item in comp)
    {
        repartitions.Add(list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Volume); // This is the line that i need to change 

    }
    var rep = repartitions;
    ViewBag.COMP = comp;
    ViewBag.REP = repartitions.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

And it return the value of the first record, but not all the records.

Comment: Do you mean you want to group? Eg you have 100 consumption records for 4 different cars and you want 4 records with the sum of each cars consumptions?

Comment: can you use `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Volumne)` instead of `.Sum(x => x.Volume)` ?

Comment: No :) I only need to select one vehicle at a time . Ex : if i have 100 consumption record , i need to have the 100 record and their value separatly and not the sum .

Comment: @HardikLeuwa I tried and i have a problem of type " Impossible to convert 'double?' in 'bool'

Comment: did you try with this  `list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Select(x => x.Volume)`  instead of  `list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Sum(x => x.Volume)` ?

Comment: @HardikLeuwa I have edited the post with your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple `GroupBy` should do the work :)

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(v => v.Snom);
foreach(var group in grouped)
{
  ViewBag.COMP = group.Key; // I place it in Viewbag 
  ViewBag.REP = group.Sum(v => v.Volume);
}
```

Comment: @Nellio Just replace the loop with that :)

Comment: I tried that :
`var comp = list.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Snom).Distinct(); // I select only the records for the selected vehicle
            var grouped = list.GroupBy(v => v.VehicleId == Snom);
            foreach (var group in grouped)
            {
                ViewBag.COMP = group.Key; // I place it in Viewbag 
                ViewBag.REP = group.Sum(v => v.Volume);
            }
            var rep = repartitions;
            ViewBag.COMP = comp;
            ViewBag.REP = repartitions.ToList();`

But nothing is drawed . Remember , i need each record , not the sum :)